# Reading a File in Pandas with quote symbol in Filename

Tags: excel, pandas, path, urllib, xlsx

I have a file name which has say the following (with apostrophe in file name)

Path = 'C:\xxx\yyy-testing\my_inner_path'

FileName = 'ABC'01myFile.xlsx'

so define File = Path + FileName

I am trying to read the file using the pandas route

```
  mydf = pd.read_excel(File, engine='openpyxl', sheet_name=sheet_name)
```

However, it is giving me error as it cannot read the apostrophe it seems. Any workaround please ( without removing the apostrophe) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make your *FileName* inside (`""`) to escape the apostrophe :

```
Path = r'C:\xxx\yyy-testing\my_inner_path'

FileName = "\ABC'01myFile.xlsx"

File = Path + FileName

mydf = pd.read_excel(File, engine='openpyxl', sheet_name=sheet_name)
```

Or use, the backslash (`\`) :

```
FileName = '\ABC\'01myFile.xlsx'
```

Answer (score 1):

First you have to use double quotes instead of single ones or use `\` to escape the character. Second, don't use `\` when you use path in Python. If you have a folder like `C:\Users`, python will complain about unicode error. Third, you should use `pathlib` to avoid add strings.

```
import pathlib

Path = pathlib.Path('C:/xxx/yyy-testing/my_inner_path')
FileName = "ABC'01myFile.xlsx"

File = Path / FileName

mydf = pd.read_excel(File, engine='openpyxl', sheet_name=sheet_name)
```